# Get name from option list <multiselect>

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-multiselect

I need to create several <multiselects>. In doing this I must identify the clicked list in some way with the purpose of passing this name to the method that makes push into the list.

By example, given these lists:

```
 List A               |    List B         |    List C          |
 --------------------------------------------------------------|
 {tag:xz   , code:1}  |{tag:pkrte,code:1} |{tag:Item1,code:1 } |
 {tag:ac   , code:2}, |{tag:bnetf,code:2},|{tag:Item2,code:2 },|
 {tag:bz   , code:3}, |{tag:erert,code:3},|{tag:Item3,code:3 },|
 {tag:hy   , code:4}, |{tag:kjerx,code:4},|                    |
 {tag:yjer , code:5}, |                   |                    |
```

I have defined this multiselects:

(simplified code to exemplify)

```html
<multiselect             |<multiselect             |<multiselect                  
  v-model="SelAlergies1" |  v-model="SelAlergies2" |  v-model="SelAlergies3"
  :height="300"          |  :height="300"          |  :height="300"               
  :options="ListA"       |  :options="ListB"       |  :options="ListC"
  :multiple="true"       |  :multiple="true"       |  :multiple="true"
  :taggable="true"       |  :taggable="true"       |  :taggable="true"
  placeholder="Alergies1"|  placeholder="Alergies2"|  placeholder="Alergies3"
  @tag="addTag('ListA')" |  @tag="addTag('ListB')" |  @tag="addTag('ListC')" 
  label="Tag"            |  label="Tag"            |  label="Tag"
  track-by="Code" >      |  track-by="Code">       |  track-by="Code" >          
</multiselect>           |</multiselect>           |</multiselect>
```

I'm trying to send the list as a parameter in the event

```
@tag="addTag('ListA')"
```

How can I pass as a parameter the name of the list (ListA, ListB. ListC )to indicate to the method which list should push?

```
addTag(newTag, listName ) {
 const tag = {
   Etiqueta: newTag,                
 };
 this.listName.push(tag);
 this.listName.push(tag);`
},
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: I need get dynamically the name of the list where it was clicked, to push the new elemnt

Comment: Isn't your clicked element saving into the `SelAlergiasMedicamentos`, your `v-model` variable?

Comment: @NehaSoni , i have edited to exemplify.